# Limited amount of future actions for Oozie Coordinator job

Tags: hadoop, action, jobs, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have created a bundle job which launches 4 coordinator job's with each coordinator job in turn starting 1 work flow ( so 4 concurrent workflows in total).

When I look at the action details for each of the coordinators I can see that it has created future actions but only for an hour ahead regardless of the frequency I have specified in the bundle properties file.

For example with a frequency of 10 minutes (*/10 * * * *) I get 6 actions created, 1st one is running, next one ready and others waiting. This is the same scenario in each of the 4 coordinator jobs. If I change the frequency to 5 minutes (*/5 * * * *) I now get 12 jobs so still just an hour into the future

What am I doing wrong, what I am trying to achieve is that each of the 4 coordinators launch their specific workflow every 10 minutes until 2099 (far in the future) but now I only get a limited number of actions per coordinator and when these have all either SUCCEEDED or KILLED no new ones are made?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What did you put for start and end attributes at the top of your coordinator?

Comment: The Start and End Date were specified in the bundle properties. The start date was passed in via the oozie cli when firing off the bundle and was set to the system time in UTC format. The End Date was set to 2099 in the properties file

Comment: I have managed to get it working. Not sure whether or not it is the correct solution but it seems to work. I came across a post that mentioned that the oozie launcher tends to deadlock things by using up all available slots in the queue. So i basically went and made an additional queue in YARN and allocated it 20% of the resources. I then specified this queue to use in the HIVE actions. This has solved the problem. Wasn't really sure what percentage of resources to allocate though to the new queue, but 20% seems fine

Comment: I can also confirm that the coordinators make actions for the current time as well as an additional 4 in the future which are in a ready/waiting state. As soon as these times and actions run a new set of 5 actions is created, so this is working fine too